# What's the color of the sahasrara chakra?

Tags: shiva, yoga, shakti, chakras, kundalini

In some sources, I read that the Sahasrara chakra is white, in others violet, and in others purple.
What is its color, and what's the meaning of the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sahasrara Chakra is all coloured.

> *“mUlAdhArAdiShaTchakra.n shaktisthAnamudIritam.h | kaNThAdupari mUrdhAnta.n shAMbhava.n sthAnamuchyate |” (Varaha Upanishad 5:53).*
>
> *“The six Chakras beginning with Muladhara are said to be the seat of Sakti (Goddess). From the neck to the top of the head is said to be the seat of Sambhu (Shiva)”.*

Through Pranayama, Kundalini uncoils herself in the Mooldhara Chakra and rises up in Sushuma Naadi (One of the nerves which passes through heart) with the help of Breath (Prana/wind) and Body heat produced during Yoga (Agni). At 1st, she pierces Brahma Granthi (Knot) near navel. Then Vishnu Knot near hear and after that Rudra Granthi near Throat and Reaches Sahasrara Chakra where Parama Shiva is residing. Thus, Shakti meets with Shiva in Sahasrara and the yogi gets liberation.

**Yoga Kundalini Upanishad.:**

> *ज्वलनाघातपवनाघातोरून्निद्रितोऽहिराट् । ब्रह्मग्रन्थिं ततो भित्त्वा विष्णुग्रन्थिं भिनत्त्यतः॥८५॥*
>
> *रुद्रग्रन्थिं च भित्त्वैव कमलानि भिनत्ति षट् । सहस्रकमले शक्तिः शिवेन सह मोदते॥८६॥*
>
> *सैवावस्था परा ज्ञेया सैव निर्वृतिकारिणी॥८७॥*
>
> *1.85-87. From the blowing of Vayu and Agni, the chief (Kundalini) pierces open the Brahmagranthi and then Vishnugranthi. Then it pierces
> Rudragranthi, after that, (all) the six lotuses (or plexuses). Then Sakti is happy with Shiva in Sahasrara Kamala (1000 lotuses seat or pineal gland). This should be known as the highest Avastha (state) and it alone is the giver of final beatitude (Moksha).*

> *“prakR^ityashhTakaruupa.n cha sthaana.n gachchhati kuNDalii | kroDiikR^itya shiva.n yaati kroDiikR^itya viliiyate |” (YogaKundalini Upanishad 1:74).*
>
> *“Kundalini assumes the eight forms of Prakriti (matter) and attains Shiva by encircling him and dissolves itself in Shiva”.*

Sahasrara Chakra is also called the city of Brahman.:

> *“taM chedbrUyuryadidamasminbrahmapure daharaM puNDarIkaM veshma daharo.asminnantarAkAshaH kiM tadatra vidyate yadanveShTavyaM yadvAva vijij~nAsitavyamiti sa brUyAt.h | (Chandogya Upanishad VIII-I-2).
> yAvAnvA ayamAkAshastAvAneSho.antarhR^idaya akAsha ubhe asmindyAvApR^ithivI antareva samAhiteubhAvagnishcha vAyushcha sUryAchandramasAvubhau vidyunnakShatrANi yachchAsyehAsti yachcha nAsti sarvaM tadasminsamAhitamiti |” (Chandogya Upanishad VIII-I-3).*
>
> *“If the disciples should say to him, ‘In this city of Brahman in which is a small mansion in the shape of a lotus and in the small inner Akasa within – what is it that lies there which should be sought, which one should desire to understand ?’ – He should say in reply, ‘As large indeed as is this Akasa, so large is that Akasa in the heart. Within it, indeed, are contained both heaven and earth, both fire and air, both the sun and the moon, lightning and the stars. Whatever there is of him in this world and whatever is not, all that is contained within it’”.*

**The colour of the Knots and the Sahasrara are as follows.:**

> *प्रथमा रक्तपीता महद्ब्रह्म दैवत्या । द्वितीया विद्युमती कृष्णा विष्णुदैवत्या । तृतीया शुभाशुभा शुक्ला रुद्रदैवत्या । यावासानेऽस्य चतुर्थ्यर्धमात्रा सा विद्युमती सर्ववर्णा पुरुषदैवत्या ।*
>
> *The first is the **red** Lord Brahma ( creative aspect ) , the second the **black** Lord Vishnu ( the administrative aspect ), the third the holy **white** Lord Rudra ( destructive aspect ) , and the fourth which is like lightning is the **all-coloured** (have all aspects) Purushothama (Shiva). **(AtharvaShikha Upanishad 1.7).***

**Maitreya Upanishad** also confirms this.:

> *सर्वदा समरूपोऽस्मि शान्तोऽस्मि पुरुषोत्तमः ।*
>
> *III-24. "I (Shiva) am always equanimous, I (Shiva) am quiescence, the greatest being (Purushottama);"*

And Also,

**Rig-Veda Khilla Part, Shiva Sankalpa Shuktam.:**

> *यो वै वेद महादेवं परमं पुरुषोत्तमम् । यः सर्व यस्य चित्सर्व तन्मे मनः शिवसंकल्पमस्तु ।। 21 ।।*
>
> *21. The one who knows the great God (Maha Deva), Om the highest of Persons (Param Purushottoma) of the vedas, Om the Supreme Self, may such my mind be of beautiful and divine resolves, be always remain filled with Auspicious Shiva-thoughts.*

"*Shri Lalita SahashraNama Stotram.:**

> *सहस्रदल-पद्मस्था सर्व-वर्णोप-शोभिता ।
> सर्वायुधधरा शुक्ल-संस्थिता सर्वतोमुखी ॥ १०९॥*
>
> *She (Lalita Tripura Sundari) is situated on a **thousand-petalled lotus** and is adorned with **all kinds of colours.**
> She is armed with all kinds of weapons and is seated on a white robe and faces all directions. ।। 109 ।।*

**Conclusion.:** So, Sahasrara Chakra is of All-Coloured and it's meaning is that, it (The city of Brahman) is the essence of the whole universe.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..